# Can you create a static variable within a member function, that is only static within an instance of that class?

Tags: c++, oop, shortcut

I'm kinda tired of always having to create a memeber for a class which will only end up getting used once in a single memeber function as a counter.
I was wondering if there was a way to declare a  variable within the class that is only static for a single instance and the next one starts with 0 again.
So what I'm basicly looking for is a shortcut for a class member within a single function

Comment: Just to understand better, what is the down side of creating a member variable? Is it because it is specific to the function and you don't want to clutter the entire class?

Comment: Can you explain why you "always" have to do this, and provide an example that illustrates what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yeah cluter, and just being able to member int counter=0; would be vrey confortable. And since its only used for maybe 3 lines of code, declaring a member seams unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is a non-static member variable, but I might be misunderstanding your question.

```
class Example
{
private:
    int mCounter;
public:
    Example() :mCounter(0)
    {
        // Empty
    }

    int increment()
    {
        mCounter++;
        return mCounter;
    }
};
```

Comment: He wants additional encapsulation of the member variable such that it is only referenced within the function using it, as if it were local to that function.  However, he will probably be forced to settle on regular member variables, like in this answer.